# Sea in Heaven : Have any interpretations, historical or modern, attempted to explain this?

Tags: heaven

Revelation 4:5-6

> And out of the throne proceeded lightnings and thunderings and voices: and there were seven lamps of fire burning before the throne, which are the seven Spirits of God. And before the throne there was a sea of glass like unto crystal: and in the midst of the throne, and round about the throne, were four beasts full of eyes before and behind.

I cannot recall any interpretation of the sea of glass. I heard one sermon where it was acknowledged as proof that Heaven is peaceful. The mention lasted mere moments and conjured up a disrespectful image that did not take the text seriously.

Is this lack of mention possibly related to Calvin not commenting on Revention?

I would be interested in hearing of any mention, or interpretation, regardless of what Church Era it occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have here a book published in 1997 which tackles the entire Book of the Revelation, and the verses you ask about are dealt with. I will quote from relevant parts explaining the meaning of chapter 4 verses 5-6, but first I would point out that the author takes verses 4-8 as setting forth four principle things, four descriptions, that all show an aspect of fourfold positions relative to the throne of God in heaven. He is keen to stress that everything in this world and that which is to come depends upon its relation to that awesome throne. (*The Revelation of Jesus Christ*, p92, John Metcalfe) Please bear that in mind as I now quote the interpretation of the sea of glass, as like crystal:

> "Before the tabernacle [on earth] and nearest to it, stood the laver,
> which ***in the later temple is called the sea***. Here the priests
> washed their hands and feet before performing their divine service,
> lest they died. Continually kept clean by the washing of water of the
> word, the washing of the saints is seen to be through the
> condescension of Christ, when he laid aside his garments, girded
> himself with a towel, and, taking a basin, washed the disciples' feet
> from the earthly dirt of this world.
>
> Here the four and twenty elders are seen as raised from the dead and
> seated in glory. There is no need of washing now. **The laver, or sea,
> is solidified, just as they are for ever purified to perfection.** The
> laver is now a sea of glass like unto crystal, a witness forever that
> its properties have more than fulfilled their function, standing in
> eternal witness to the effectual washing of the saints or ever they
> were raised from the dead to ascend in glory, to be seated in view of
> this everlasting testimony to the grace of God that bringeth
> salvation." (*Ibid*. pp 100-101 - emphases mine)

The interpretation calls upon the Old Testament basin, called the laver, or the Sea (Exodus 40:30-32 & 2 Kings 16:17), to show the need for the priests of God to wash in water in a particular way, otherwise they would die. In the earthly temple, the Sea was a great bronze basin placed atop four bronze oxen. But, having been properly washed, they could enter fully into that divine service of God. The New Testament speaks of all believers in Christ being "priests and kings unto God" - Rev. 1:6 & 5:10 & 20:6. All believers in Christ have been properly washed by him, and then there is the illustration of Christ washing the feet of the disciples (John 13:14 but note vss 8-10).

This leaves us with the matter of how we will relate to the sea of glass before God's throne of glory. Only those who have been cleansed - washed - by Christ will ever see that throne and that solid crystal 'sea' of glass. But if we try to get clean any other way than by Christ cleansing us, we won't be there.

Comment: Nice find. Compelling interpretation.

Comment: That is intriguing in the interpretation connecting to the Elders.

Answer (score 1):

Update to my above question:

I was able to find an interpretation by Victorinus of Pettau, 3rd century, in his commentary on The Apocalypse. On the quality of the following translation, I have no way of forming a basis of opinion.

> And before the throne there was, as it were, a sea of glass like to crystal. That is the gift of baptism which He sheds forth through His Son in time of repentance, before He executes judgment. It is therefore before the throne, that is, the judgment. And when he says a sea of glass like to crystal, he shows that it is pure water, smooth, not agitated by the wind, not flowing down as on a slope, but given to be immoveable as the house of God.

My takeaway from this interpretation:

1. The vision and the Sea itself are not real.
2. The purpose of at least this portion of the Apocalypse, is to convey doctrinal principles, rather then tangible reality.
3. Ironically, it has some crossover to the sermon mentioned in the original question, where the Sea tells us Heaven is peaceful. Both are allegorical and concern a state of mind, not a factual reality.

I next reviewed an online sermon by Chuck Smith as a contrast to a modern Dispensationalist.

Smith gave a typical sermon, short on details. He read the text and made statements largely confined to a stop and start dramatic reading. The Sea was mentioned in reading the text only, without explanation given. I feel Smith is fairly representative of a typical Evangelical sermon covering Chapter 4, whether Dispensational or not.

Do alternative interpretations exist?